# Why doesn't For each loop go to Next sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I need to handle an Excel workbook with multiple tabs, and format dates.

I have found a way to format one date, and I wanted to put a loop around it. However the loop does not work, and it only updates one sheet.

```
Sub dotoall()

 
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim FindCol As Range
    Dim sAdd As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each Sheet In Worksheets

Set ws = ActiveSheet 

    
    With ws
    
     
    
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'find first instance where DATE exists in row 1 (headers)
        Set FindCol = .Rows(1).Find(What:="DTE", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False, SearchFormat:=False)
                    
    
  
    
                 
        'store address of first found instance (to check in loop)
sAdd = FindCol.Address




        
        Do
        
        
        
            'format column (row 2 to last used row)
            .Range(.Cells(2, FindCol.Column), .Cells(LastRow, FindCol.Column)).NumberFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"
        

            'find next instance (begin search after current instance found)
            Set FindCol = .Cells.FindNext(After:=FindCol)
            
        'keep going until nothing is found or the loop finds the first address again (in which case the code can stop)
        Loop Until FindCol Is Nothing Or FindCol.Address = sAdd
     
    End With
        


Next Sheet




End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
For Each Sheet In Worksheets
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

You want just:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
```

Comment: Thanks. The loop works. I am now stuck with another problem, but the loop works!